# IF/THEN statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Let me start by saying I'm new to programming.  I have a question around categorizing something similar to using an IF/THEN statement in Excel.  I have this:

```
visit_id        action
1   sale 
1   sale 
1   sale 
2   service
2   service
3   sale 
3   sale 
3   service
```

I want to get this:

```
visit   category
1   sale 
2   service
3   both
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: could you tell what you need ? what you have tried till now and what exact issue you are facing

Comment: I'm confused as to what Excel has to do with this. If this is an SQL question, then `select visit_id as visit, action as category from yourtable group by visit`?

Comment: what RDBMS is this? are "sale" and "service" the only two that should always make up "both" or is it dynamic?

Comment: It seems like he is asking how to handle IF/Then cases in SQL

Comment: Note that OP wants to aggregate the results to get **"BOTH"** as a result

Comment: Yes, sorry...I'm trying to figure out how to handle IF/THEN cases in SQL.

Comment: Are you using `Excel`? I have edited the question to include the tag per your post.

Comment: What sql statement have you used to generate the first table?

Comment: please share RDBMS name. Is it sql server/ oracle???

Comment: I have visit_id's that can have multiple actions...sales or service.  I want to then be able to categorize them into being a sales visit, a service visit or both.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I've tried using a CASE statement but it only seems to look at the first record and not all records associated with the visit_id.

Answer (score 3):

Try using case when :

```
SELECT visit_id,
       CASE
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN action = 'sale' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = Count(*) THEN 'sale'
         WHEN Sum(CASE
                    WHEN action = 'service' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END) = Count(*) THEN 'service'
         ELSE 'both'
       END
FROM   table
--WHERE  action in('sale','service')
GROUP  BY visit_id
```

Assumed that you have only two types of `action` i.e. `sale` and `service`.

Comment: double case statements, very clever. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well.. someone started to write about CASE in selects, but then deleted his answer, I don't know why.. That's what CASE is for, but you also need another step.

- First, you need to actually categorize the rows depending on your criteria, and write the results to NEW, SEPARATE columns. That's the place where CASE comes in
- Then, you need to groupby over that criteria and aggregate the results
- Then, you need to translate the aggregated results into what-you-finally-want

Examples in T-SQL dialect:

Step 1:

```
select
    visit_id,
    case action when 'sale' then 1 else 0 end as actionIsSale,
    case action when 'service' then 1 else 0 end as actionIsService
from fooTable
```

Step 2:

```
select
    visit_id,
    max(actionIsSale) as hasSale,
    max(actionIsService) as hasService
from (previousquery)
group by visit_id
```

Step 3:

```
select
    visit_id as visit,
    case
        when hasSale='1' and hasService='0' then 'sale'
        when hasSale='0' and hasService='1' then 'service'
        when hasSale='1' and hasService='1' then 'both'
        else '!WTF!'
    end as category
from (previousquery)
```

Summed up:

```
select
    step2.visit_id as visit,
    case
        when step2.hasSale='1' and step2.hasService='0' then 'sale'
        when step2.hasSale='0' and step2.hasService='1' then 'service'
        when step2.hasSale='1' and step2.hasService='1' then 'both'
        else '!WTF!'
    end as category
from
(
    select
        step1.visit_id,
        max(step1.actionIsSale) as hasSale,
        max(step1.actionIsService) as hasService
    from
    (
        select
            visit_id,
            case action when 'sale' then 1 else 0 end as actionIsSale,
            case action when 'service' then 1 else 0 end as actionIsService
        from fooTable

    ) as step1
    group by step1.visit_id

) as step2
```

Note #1: when gluing the parts together, I used the steps directly as subqueries, so I had to assign aliases (`as step1`, `as step2` etc). That's a specific requirement in T-SQL/SqlServer, your DB may don't care, but that's a good thing anyways.

Note #2: if you don't like such subqueries, you can easily split all of into temporary tables or CTEs or whatever; what counts is the idea of performing data transformations in short steps and simple operations

Note #3: this code can have minor flaws and syntax errors, I have written it in one go and have not tried executing it. However you should have now the overall idea and it should be very easy to follow and correct any bits.

Note #4: after you understand how it works, you can try to pack it into much shorter query that will i.e. collapse the Step2 and Step3 into a single expression, and the you'll notice that you can pack it with Step1 too, to do all of that in one query. You will get something like **Deepak Pawar** written. While my "solution" may seem excessively bloated compared to his, especially for this simple problem, the "expand into new columns and aggregate" trick works for many more complicated cases ;)